# looping array not working

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this code that I am using for a basket, I can't seem to work out how to add to cost variable.

```
var basket = {};
basket.items = [];
basket.costCalculate = function() {
    var cost = 0,
        html = "Total: " + cost;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        cost = (cost + parseInt(this.items[i].price));
    };
    return html;
};
basket.print = function() {
    var basketCon = document.getElementById("basket"),
        html = "";
    basketCon.innerHTML = "<h1>Basket - " + this.costCalculate() + "</h1>";
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        html += '<div class="item">';
        for(prop in this.items[i]) {
            if(prop != "id") {
                html += '<p><span class="title">' + prop + '</span>: ' + this.items[i][prop] + '</p>';
            }
        };
        html += '</div>';
    };
    basketCon.innerHTML += html;
};

function init() {
    shop.print()
    basket.handler();
};
window.onload = init;
```

I have been trying to loop through the length of the items array and sum up the cost fields. Does not seem to work however. Is there something very basic that I am doing wrong?

Comment: what should do cost === (cost + parseInt(this.items[i].price));?

Comment: "Does not seem to work however" What specifically is not working? Is `costCalculate()` being called? Is it iterating through the loop? Is it just the addition that's not working?

Comment: Try putting console.log('var is:', someVar) to find problems.

Comment: @PatrickQ Was not very clear was I, when I run add to the basket the cost does not update.

Comment: You're still not being clear. First, you've dramatically changed your code by changing the `===` to `=`. Which is it in your actual code? You should always post the exact code your using, instead of trying to transcribe it, or condense it. Second, you should try to narrow down the problem. You say "the cost does not update", but there are a number of steps along the way to making that happen. Where is the failure? Are you getting any errors in your JS console? Follow Vall3y's advice and add some log statements to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the [identity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) operator. You're not assigning a value.
`cost === (cost + parseInt(this.items[i].price));`

Should be:

`cost += parseInt(this.items[i].price);`

And the rest:

```
var basket = {};
basket.items = [{price:10}, {price:"10"} /*,{price:"nan"}*/];

basket.costCalculate = function () {
    var cost = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        // Breaks for NaN values
        cost = (cost + parseInt(this.items[i].price));
    }
    return cost;
};

basket.print = function () {
    var basketCon = document.getElementById("basket"),
        html = "";
    basketCon.innerHTML = "<h1>Basket - Cost: " + this.costCalculate() + "</h1>";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        html += '<div class="item">';
        for (var prop in this.items[i]) {
            if (prop != "id") {
                html += '<p><span class="title">' + prop + '</span>: ' + this.items[i][prop] + '</p>';
            }
        }
        html += '</div>';
    }
    basketCon.innerHTML += html;
};

function init() {
    //shop.print();
    basket.print();
}

window.onload = init;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fk4Lc1hn/3/)**

Comment: No, there's plenty of more wrong with your code... You're not returning `cost` either.

Comment: Cost returns within html.

Comment: @hudsond7 No it doesn't. You only set `html` before the loop, you don't update it within (or after) the loop. So `html` will always be `Total: 0`. Move the assignment to be after the loop and see what happens.